# Select rows with incremental column value

Tags: r, dplyr

I have data like this:

```
SNP  chr pos   
 A1    1   2 
 A2    1   3   
 A3    1   4  
 A4    1 4.5
 A5    1   6
```

My real data is bigger with several different 'chr'.

I would like to select rows based on 'pos' column value with constant increment (let say 2). If I select A1 and then my next selection is A3 and then A5, it means difference 2 is fixed and some time it may be around 2.

I tried with `dplyr::between`, but I am not successfull with that.

```
filter(df, between(pos, 2, 4))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)
## I've extended the sample data for experimenting with the desired output
SNP <- paste0('A', 1:10)
chr <- rep(1, 10)
pos <- c(2, 3, 4, 4.5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 12) ## Asuming there are no duplicate values
df <- cbind.data.frame(SNP, chr, pos)

## Create a helper function to generate the possible incremental value
selector <- function(start_val, end_val, increment){
  return(seq(start_val, end_val, by = increment))
} 

## initiate start_val & increment as per your choice
start_val <- 2
increment <- 2
  

df_filtered <- df %>%
  filter(pos %in% selector(start_val, end_val = start_val * n(), increment)) %>%
  arrange(pos) %>%
  mutate(checkpoint = start_val + increment * (row_number() -1),
         id = row_number()) %>%
  filter(id < (
    if_else(sum(FALSE == (pos == checkpoint)) > 0,
            which((pos == checkpoint) == FALSE)[1], (n() + 1L)
            ))) %>%
    select(SNP:pos)
  
df_filtered
```

Comment: Forhad Excellant your solution working as per my need Thanks a lot for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `seq` function -

```
n <- 2
start_row <- 1
result <- df[seq(start_row, nrow(df), n), ]
result$SNP
```